# Probability of drawing $N$ or less balls without replacement until three red balls are drawn

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve **part a** of the following question (from Pitman's Probability):

A box contains $3$ red balls, $4$ blue balls, and $6$ green balls.  Balls are drawn one-by-one without replacement until all the red balls are drawn.  Let $D$ be the number of draws made.  Calculate:  a) $P(D \leq 9)$; b) $P(D = 9)$; c) $E(D)$.

The solution is given as $$\frac {10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}{13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10}$$ but I don't understand why this is correct. I get the feeling that there is a symmetry argument here (e.g $P(D \le 9) = 1 - P(D \ge 10)$ ) but I'm not sure how to evaluate  the latter expression.

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing so special. Think of picking all 13 balls at once, and here, we only care about if in the first 9, we observed all the red balls. Equivalently, we can just check if in the last 4 balls, we didn't see any red balls, so we only saw blue and green. So we are really just looking at the number of ways we can pick 4 balls, none of which are red, out of all 4 ball combinations. The numerator is thus the number of ways we can pick only blue and green (there are 10 such balls), as we have 10 choices for the first ball, then 9 for the second, etc. On the denominator, we are looking at all such sequences, so now we have 13 choices for the first ball, 12 for the second, etc.